# Creating loop that pulls back every three months until 6 months are pulled - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

How can I create a loop to print every 3 months ago until it gives me back 6 months? For example, I want the loop to pull back dates like this 202012, 202009, 202006, 202003, 201912, 201909, essentially skipping every 3 until it does it for 6 times.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample data and _code_ for what you've tried so far so that we can understand how to help

Comment: Your question asks for `6 months`, your text `6 times`.  Could you put your code and data to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that when you say 'gives me back 6 months' you mean generates 6 different months, including the starting month:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

date = datetime.datetime.strptime("202003", "%Y%m")
delta = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=3)

print(date.strftime("%Y%m"))
for _ in range(5):
    date += delta
    print(date.strftime("%Y%m"))

# edit: I see OP wanted to go back in time. The += should be -=
```